# Graphiql gives correct output from Node.js backend but React Apollo client (with same query) gives the wrong output

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo, graphiql

The gist of my question is in the title.

So I made simple GraphQL backend with Node.js. When I check it with GraphiQL it works fine. But the same query I use with GraphQL does not work when I fetch it with React (Apollo) client. It doesn't throw the error, it displays data, but with incorrect values (it mixes the values from different entries but with no clear pattern).

The query is

```
query{
  getAllUsers{
    id
    name,
    email,
    roles {
      id
      role
    }
  }
}
```

The id, name and email are always correct, both in GraphiQL and React client, but roles are correct in GraphiQL, and always mixed up in React-Apollo client. I'm not expert in GraphQl so I asking someone who is - what I am doing wrong?

Comment: bad ids? the same ids for different users and roles, overwritten during  normalization [in cache]? .... show example response/data?

Comment: You know what, you are right. When I make dummy data with different id numbers, everything is ok. Thanks you for your answer, it solved my problem.